Is it possible for plant life to evolve (and adapt) on a low CO2 planet?

C4 photosynthesis, which can operate in Carbon Dioxide levels as low as 10ppm
A question related to these two questions:
Habitable inner planet with large oceans, fast rotation and earth-like atmosphere
Mass extinction because of too low CO2-levels
I am designing a habitable inner planet which has high insolation, and according to my calculations, requires a bond albedo of 0.412 and Carbon Dioxide as low as 10ppm (partial pressure equivalent in 1 atm) in order to maintain an average temperature of 35°C.
Plant life on Earth (such as C3 photo-synthesisers) will largely die out in CO2 levels lower than 170ppm. C4 plants will begin to die at levels lower than 10ppm.
Given how vulnerable plants on my alien inner planet world will be to dying out, they will have to evolve some way to be able to continue photosynthesis in levels of CO2 even lower than 10ppm, (perhaps as low as 1ppm). The carbon-silicate cycle on my world will be really delicate thanks to a huge amount of weathering (thanks to more sunlight).
My question:
Can I have plants evolve/adapt on my world to work with levels of CO2 <10ppm? Are there any factors I have to consider to have this be possible?
Bonus (if possible to answer):
Can I also have human-breathable levels of Oxygen in the atmosphere of this world?

I would suggest that making even a simple gross mechanical estimation of possible plant growth rate at 10 ppm CO2 would be worthwhile. Assuming a pressure of 1 atmosphere and 100% efficiency in the use of carbon dioxide, a plant would need to extract all the carbon dioxide in 400 cubic meters of air to grow by one gram... (The compare the amount of oxygen released with the amount lost to geological processes. And you would need to wait 40 or 50 years for a field of wheat or whatever to produce the same amount of edible seeds as a field here on Earth produces in one year.)

@AlexP would it be possible for plant life to evolve be able to extract less carbon dioxide and yet grow the same amount?

They cannot grow more than what carbon they fix... Plant mass is mostly various carbohydrates (mostly cellulose, starch and sugar) and of course lots of water. The water is water, taken as is from the environment. The carbohydrates are 40% to 44% carbon by mass; the point is that the carbon obtained from carbon dioxide is 40 to 44 percent of the dry mass of the plant. The plant releases one mole of oxygen for each mole of carbon dioxide it fixes.

what else is in the atmopshere? if there is enough oxygen organisms will use that up turning it inot co2, the ocygen co2 balance on earth is controlled mostly by life not geology. also there are photosynthetic bacteria that do not use co2 so non-co2 photosythesis is possile, but it will only work in the ocean.

Yes, nothing forbids it, except that lesser CO2 means slower growth.

What's the bulk geochemistry like? Does the planetary crust contain an Earthlike amount of Carbon? Also what else is the atmosphere made of?

The planet has oxygen in the atmosphere like Earth, oceans like Earth and has Carbon in the crust. CO2 is just low in the atmosphere due to weathering (thanks to high stellar flux). The planet’s early history was spent further away from the star and migrated inwards over time as life developed.

If it has earth like levels of Oxygen and life then it will have earth like levels of co2, oxygen on earth is made from paleo co2. An earth planet is not going to have high oxygen levels without starting with high CO2. you can't have dramatically low CO2 AND high oxygen.

@John The planet started more within the habitable zone and thus had more CO2, allowing for oxygenation to take place. The planet later migrated inwards and this caused weathering to lower the CO2 and I am wondering if carbon-fixing plants can adapt to this change (and oxygen levels to not drop too much) if it happens slowly enough.

@casualworldbuilder the only way oxygen levels will not drop dramatically is if there is no life, living things are constantly turning oxygen into co2. It would only take a few million years to deplete the oxygen.

@John increased photodissociation of water aka abiotic oxygen could compensate lower biotic oxygen production, if this is even a problem (life could perhaps adapt to consume less oxygen). I’ll see what the current answerers have to say.

I'm not sure how much help this is going to be but I would advise asking yourself these questions: - Do you actually need oxygen in the atmosphere? Depending on what you need the outcome of the design to be, maybe plants won't have to produce oxygen. Also consider a type of star, the planet's distance from it, and the radiation it emits the most. All of those factors will play a role in the evolution of the environment and thus the plants. (helpful topics: great oxidation event, purple earth hypothesis) - **What other gasses are in your atmosphere and what is the chemical composition of th

I would suggest that plants, as in photosynthetic, carbon fixing, primary producers could well survive with such a low atmospheric CO2. I would suggest that their populations are going to be geographically bounded and occur only in areas with carbonaceous, and carbonate rocks. On carbonates they'll be nitrogen fixers using the acids produced by that process to dissolve the, relatively carbon rich, substrate. On carbonaceous regolith they'll also need to be nitrogen fixers because they have no other access to nitrogen and they'll use more usual root enzymes to take up carbon from the underlying material. Obviously the photosynthetic pathway(s) are going to be very different to most of our modern plants but there was a lot of photosynthesis going on pre-GOE that also bears no resemblance to the biochemical pathways we usually think of when we say plants.
As to the bonus question; there is no reason that such plants, having evolved from plants that themselves evolved at higher atmospheric CO2 won't still pull down atmospheric CO2, when it's available and produce oxygen through familiar biochemical pathways. The species that eat carbonates will dump waste oxygen into the atmosphere and at a slightly higher rate than when taking in CO2. They're metabolising a mole of CO32- for each mole of carbon and producing 1.5 moles of O2. They'll probably pump out O2 because O3 is biochemically problematic due to its reactivity. Plants that eat coal and similar substrates on the other hand are going to put out very little in the way of usable oxygen.

In fact there's real world Chara algae which can do that, typically growing underwater in limestone-rich areas. In their case, nitrogen fixation seems to be done by associated cyanobacteria.

Will this also work with Earth-like oxygen levels?

@silvado Nitrogen fixation usually is done by a symbiotic organism, either a bacterium or a fungus.

@casualworldbuilder Yes but it's higher energy than gaseous extraction, it only becomes necessary/preferred when the atmospheric carbon content is way down.

@Ash indeed, but the linked paper just states that the cyanobacteria are "associated", so I didn't want to claim that they'd be symbiotic.

@casualworldbuilder Bonus question addressed.

@Ash Thanks, I rewarded your answer. I was a little confused if I could still have Oxygen because I received conflicting answers about it.

@casualworldbuilder You're welcome. There's no real reason you can't so if you want it you can have it.

One possible solution for too low carbon-dioxide in the atmosphere has been proposed in one of the earliest worldbuilding project, the Epona project. Epona is a hypothetical planet around the star 82 Eridani. Plants are capable of absorbing atmospheric carbon dioxide at night, storing the gas inside bubble-like leaves. During the day, the plants have lots of carbon dioxide and can photosynthesize. Amazingly enough, cacti use a somewhat similar system called the CAM or Crassulacean Acid Metabolism (sometimes abbrevieted to C4, in contrast to normal and more common C3). C4 has evolved independently among many plant families, including pineapples. However, on Earth the reason behind this evolution is arid conditions: Respiration during the day loses more water, so plants absorb the gas during the night and store it in their tissues for the daytime. on Epona, the reason is quite different: It is a planet roughly half the size of Earth, and therefore its volcanic activity is dying, causing the carbon cycle to be disrupted.
I have found no reference to plants on Earth extracting carbon dioxide from carbonate rocks or decaying organic matter through the roots. It may be present somewhere in the universe. However, a lower concentration of carbon dioxide when volcanic activity subsides also means low greenhouse gas concentrations and temperatures may drop. The plants may therefore face two challenges, not just one.

The low greenhouse concentrations isn’t only not a problem, but necessary for the planet I have in mind. It receives a lot of insolation and at its current state, if it had earth levels of CO2, it would risk runaway greenhouse.

"CAM or Crassulacean Acid Metabolism, sometimes abbrevieted to C4": CAM and C4 photosythetic pathways are not the same. CAM is less efficient than C4, but CAM wastes much less water, making it more suitable for plants growing is arid conditions.

I would say, think of it from a different perspective. If you think of plant life in terms of Earth like plants, then these plants would probably would not adapt well. Plants that evolved on this plant had to go through a long line of changes and process that change itself, changed other organisms and changed the world as time progressed.
I will build a bit on the suggestion the previous answer. There are other sources of carbon out there other than from the atmosphere. Earth plants use CO2 because it is there and readily accessible. On your planet, it is there, but not in concentrations as on Earth (~420 ppm) which Earth plants thrive on.
The rocks ash mentioned carbonaceous and other carbon rich minerals can be broke down by alien biological process not found on Earth to be readily absorbed by the plants root system. This process would produce CO2, but this would be hungerly consumed by the plants, which could explain the abnormally low free CO2 and not have a run away greenhouse effect. This process, over time would allow for the build up of carbonate (many of which is created by biological processes already), such as lime stone to form, continuing the cycle.
However, without high levels of CO2 in the atmosphere, there may be carbon sinks that may lock up carbon from being usable, such as biological runoff into the ocean, over geological time. To solve this, there may be a need to have high geological activity that constantly recycles carbon from the ocean back to the land. Otherwise life in the ocean may thrive, but life on land would suffer.
